# Calculating and printing points averages

Tags: mysql, average

I am trying to calculate the average score for each player in a MySQL database and then output the information with PHP. The basic table structure includes `record_id`, `name`, `score`, for example:

```
record_id   name     score
--------------------------
1           Bob       2
2           Jim       1
3           Bob       3
4           Bob       3
5           Jim       2
6           Jim       3
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
Name    Average Score
--------------------
Bob     2.66
Jim     2
```

Comment: How did you come up with "Bob 2.66"? Couldn't you attempt to write a program that uses the same mechanism? :)

Comment: @Tomalak It was a rhetorical question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of MySQL to calculate the average already for you:

```
SELECT name, AVG(score) AS average_score FROM players GROUP BY name
```

You can find all about MySQL in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name`, AVG(`score`) FROM `basic table` GROUP BY `name`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, avg(score) as average_score from mytable group by name
```

the mysql manual is great as it has lots of examples. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name`, AVG(`score`) AS `average`
  FROM `table`
 GROUP BY `name`
```